# Restrict Docker exposed port from only specific IP adresses

Tags: networking, docker, iptables

How to restrict a container's port exposed by Docker from only a list of IPs? Only this list of IP would be able to access this port.

I tried that:

```
iptables -I DOCKER -p tcp --dport PORT_X -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
iptables -I DOCKER -p tcp --dport PORT_X --source EXTERNAL_IP_1 --destination HOST_IP_1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I DOCKER -p tcp --dport PORT_X --source EXTERNAL_IP_2 --destination HOST_IP_1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I DOCKER -p tcp --dport PORT_X --source EXTERNAL_IP_3 --destination HOST_IP_1 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Does this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30769829/docker-ignores-iptable-rules-when-using-p-portport?rq=1

Comment: iptables are order sensitive. You're rejecting before you ever get to your accept rules.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem. I solved it with this rules :

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i <your_interface_name> -j DROP
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i <your_interface_name> -s <your_first_ip> -j ACCEPT
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i <your_interface_name> -s <your_second_ip> -j ACCEPT
```

Care, `DOCKER-USER` is a chain which will not be deleted when `service docker restart`

You should be able to add your port flag, but i'm not an expert and it is not my needs.

Answer (score 7):

Your policy is whitelist, it's better to create a user custom `chain` handle this alone.

For example, I have a `redis` container, I want it only serve for specific IPs:

```
$ docker run -d -p 6379:6379 redis:2.8
```

After started redis container, the `iptables` looks like this:

```
$ iptables -t filter -nL
Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:6379
```

Create our custom chain:

```
$ iptables -N CUSTOM_REDIS
$ iptables -A CUSTOM_REDIS -p tcp --dport 6379 --source 172.31.101.37 --destination 172.17.0.2 -j ACCEPT
$ iptables -A CUSTOM_REDIS -p tcp --dport 6379 --source 172.31.101.38 --destination 172.17.0.2 -j ACCEPT
$ iptables -A CUSTOM_REDIS -p tcp --dport 6379 --source 0.0.0.0/0 --destination 172.17.0.2 -j DROP
```

Replace the original rule with custom chain:

```
$ iptables -R DOCKER 1 -p tcp --source 0.0.0.0/0 --destination 172.17.0.2 --dport 6379 -j CUSTOM_REDIS
```

Now my redis can only access by ip: `172.31.101.37` and `172.31.101.38`.

**Note:**

- `172.17.0.2` is the ip of redis container

Comment: I am facing same issue and I am still trying to get my brain around Docker.  Currently, I create the container containing java rest service and I forward to Devop to deploy.   I am wondering if this script is something that I can embed in a Dockerfile?    Thanks

Comment: If you specify the --destination 172.17.0.2 you are tying your rules for a specific IP which might change in your next restart

Answer (score 4):

From the docker guide [here](https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/#restrict-connections-to-the-docker-daemon):

> Docker’s forward rules permit all external source IPs by default. To allow only a specific IP or network to access the containers, insert a negated rule at the top of the DOCKER filter chain. For example, to restrict external access such that only source IP 8.8.8.8 can access the containers, the following rule could be added:

`$ iptables -I DOCKER -i ext_if ! -s 8.8.8.8 -j DROP`

In  your case since you want to allow multiple IP addresses I think something like this should work:

```
iptables -I DOCKER -s EXTERNAL_IP_1 -p tcp --dport PORT_X -j ACCEPT
iptables -I DOCKER -s EXTERNAL_IP_2 -p tcp --dport PORT_X -j ACCEPT
iptables -I DOCKER -s EXTERNAL_IP_3 -p tcp --dport PORT_X -j ACCEPT
iptables -I DOCKER -p tcp --dport PORT_X -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

Comment: I want to restrict specefic container

Answer (score 4):

You may also want to prevent access from docker directly, using the specific IP you want to listen, like -p 1.2.3.4:6379:6379/tcp syntax, that way the container will listen only on that IP and interface.

If you use that IP as private IPs, you can avoid completely the iptables because you restricted access only from local/private network.

Answer (score -3):

You can use ufw from inside docker container

```
sudo ufw [--dry-run] [delete] [insert NUM]  allow|deny|reject|limit  [in|out on INTERFACE] [log|log-all] [proto protocol] [from ADDRESS [port PORT]][to ADDRESS [port PORT]]
```