# Restrict connections to the Docker host for several subnets

Tags: docker, networking, iptables

I need to restrict connections to a docker container. The [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/#restrict-connections-to-the-docker-host) states the following:

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i ext_if ! -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j DROP
```

After this the DOCKER-USER chain starts looking like this:

```
Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  -- !192.168.1.0/24       anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

This works fine, there is access from 192.168.1.0/24 subnet and none from the rest. But my problem is that I need to add several subnets. I tried replacing this one line with several lines but without success

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER 1 -i ext_if -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j RETURN
iptables -I DOCKER-USER 2 -i ext_if -s 10.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
iptables -I DOCKER-USER 3 -j DROP
```

The chain starts to look like this:

```
Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  192.168.1.0/24       anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  10.0.0.0/24          anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Also tried `ACCEPT` instead of `RETURN` but the result was the same - everything gets dropped, regardless of the subnet it comes from.

Is there a way to split the working one line into several?

P.S. I know that I can list the subnets separated by comma, but it's undesirable because I need to add about 15 of them with a comment for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50656550/10842470).
The interface should be specified in the `DROP` line.

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER 1 -i ext_if -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j RETURN
iptables -I DOCKER-USER 2 -i ext_if -s 10.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
iptables -I DOCKER-USER 3 -i ext_if -j DROP
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).